# Complex SQL inner join and conditional field to LINQ. (My LINQ produces duplicates.)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm fairly new to LINQ and in need of help making my SQL conversion to LINQ work. I'm building a Status field based upon other field values and my LINQ code is producing some duplicate rows, i.e. if there is a Status = "Failure" then a Status = "Success" row is also produced.

The SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Employee_ID
, T.Termination_date
, T.office_country_nm
, T.ticket_no
, T.ticket_url
, T.hold
, Status = 
CASE 
WHEN log.Message LIKE 'GeneralFail' THEN 'Failure'
WHEN log.Level LIKE 'Information' THEN 'Success' 
WHEN log.Level LIKE 'Debug' THEN 'Success' 
WHEN log.Level LIKE 'Error' THEN 'Failure' 
WHEN log.Level LIKE 'Warning' THEN 'Failure' ELSE 'Pending (' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), DATEADD(dd, 4, T.Termination_date))) + ' days)' 
END 
FROM wd_ad_terms T LEFT OUTER JOIN wd_ad_terms_log log ON T.ticket_no =   log.midasticket AND log.midasticket <> '' AND log.midasticket IS NOT NULL 
WHERE (T.office_country_nm = @country OR T.office_country_nm IS NULL OR T.office_country_nm = '') 
ORDER BY T.Termination_date DESC, T.Employee_ID
```

My attempted LINQ:

```
var employees = (from term in dc.wd_ad_terms.Distinct()
             join log in dc.wd_ad_terms_log on term.ticket_no equals log.midasticket into termlog
             where term.office_country_nm == country && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(country)
             from log in termlog.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                term.Employee_ID,
                term.Termination_date,
                term.office_country_nm,
                term.ticket_no,
                term.ticket_url,
                term.hold,
                Status = (log.Message == "GeneralFail" || log.Level == "Error" || log.Level == "Warning" ? "Failure" :
                              log.Level == "Information" || log.Level == "Debug" ? "Success" :
                              "Pending")
             });
```

Thank you for any help!
Paul

Comment: In general move the `.Distinct()` at the end (just before the final `;`)

Comment: while good practice, and thanks, it doesn't resolve the issue. I should mention that if I remove the Status assignment, make like Status="Pending", no duplicate rows are produced. So it appears something to do with my assigning value to Status formula. Thx.

Comment: Well, that was the obvious difference between your SQL and LINQ queries. Another one that I see now (not sure if important) is that the SQL query uses `LIKE` conditions inside the `Status` expression while LINQ query is using `==`. In order to make them equivalent, additionally to what I said about `Distinct`, you might consider changing `==` to `.Contains`.

Comment: Try using Linqpad, it converts SQL to LINQ.

Comment: @Ivan Good thinking. I'll try that.

Comment: @Shan Awesome! I figured there had to be something like that available. I'll try that.

Comment: @Shan Well I can't figure out how to convert SQL to LINQ in linqpad and stuff I'm reading says it can't. Am I missing something, ie library reference?